# OOP instance updating

Tags: python, oop

I just started With OOP and i am confused with this code-

```
class cartesianPoint:

       pass

cp1 = cartesianPoint()

cp1.x = 1.0

cp1.y = 2.0

cp1

>
<__main__.cartesianPoint instance at 0x0000000001E7EB88>
```

Firstly Why I am able to add new variables to object which do not belong to the Class?If class is a blueprint for objects,shouldnt the objects follow the buleprint ? And even though python allows you to do so, why does the object still belong to the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check section 9.4 here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

> Note that clients may add data attributes of their own to an instance object without affecting the validity of the methods, as long as name conflicts are avoided

**cp1** is indeed an instance of the **CartesianPoint** class but you have added 2 new data members to that specific instance which has no effect on the class itself or any subsequent instances.

Keep in mind that each instance of the CartesianPoint class has its own dict of fields and methods.

Comment: But why cp1 is still an instance of cartesianPoint even after addind two data memebers specific to cp1???

Comment: check that link: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Add_a_variable_to_a_class_instance_at_runtime#Python

Comment: You can think of that simply as: Python is a dynamic scripting language, so It allows the users to define object data members and methods dynamically but Python will not bind it back to the class of that object. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python tutorial - Classes - Instance Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects):

> data attributes correspond to “instance variables” in Smalltalk, and
>   to “data members” in C++. Data attributes need not be declared; like
>   local variables, they spring into existence when they are first
>   assigned to.

Using [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), you can prevent new instance variable being assigned.